# Connecting, building and manipulating a JQuery UI with underlying client-side JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am using a static JSON file which is used to populate a JQuery-based sortable list.

For example:

```
[
     { "id": 0, "movie_name": "Manhattan", "location":"NY" },
     { "id": 1, "movie_name": "A Wonderful Life" }
]
```

The web page iterates through the JSON array and builds a sortable list of the movie_name field plus additional text boxes for each which allows, for example, the user to enter a review. The user is also allowed to re-order the list which would eventually be persisted server-side. Each item may have fields which don't appear in other items, for example, 'location' in the first item, but not the second. The 'id' field is present in each item and represents the unique identifier of the movie, but is not displayed.

Once complete, I would like the user to be able to submit the list back to the server with the details added or re-ordered as JSON, something along the lines of:

```
[
     { "id": 1, "movie_name": "A Wonderful Life", "review":"user entered data" }
     { "id": 0, "movie_name": "Manhattan", "location":"NY", "review":"user entered data" },
]
```

I'm not sure the best way to maintain and build the JSON array which is sent back to the server.

My main question is, how do I connect the UI components back to the underlying JSON object as they are manipulated and submitted?

Is it best to update the underlying JSON data as the fields are changed (if so, how?), or rebuild the JSON data once the user submits the data (the latter method wouldn't necessarily have visibility to all the non-displayed fields).

Hopefully that makes sense. :)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You would never do anything directly with the JSON data. You would parse it into native JS data structures, i.e. arrays and objects, and modify those. Then you'd convert them back to JSON and send the encoded data to the server. For data <-> UI connections, you might want to have a look at knockout.js: http://knockoutjs.com/.

Comment: Thanks Felix, I will take a look. Looks very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is a data format, not data. In your example you should in page load parse those json to some hash-like object by ids. Then on each ui update -- update that object.
Lately on submit -- convert that object back to array-like structure and then only transromt it to JSON. Now you will have it on server.

Comment: Thanks, I think between your answer and Felix's comment, that answers the question. :)